# Recursive Query - Only select nodes where leaf nodes represent active data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, hierarchy

Given the following recursive query:

```
WITH DepartmentHierarchy (DepartmentID, Name, IsInactive, IsSpecial, ParentId, HierarchyLevel) AS
(
   -- Base case
   SELECT
      DepartmentId,
      Name,
      IsInactive,
      IsSpecial,
      ParentId,
      1 as HierarchyLevel
   FROM StoreDepartment
   WHERE ParentId IS NULL

   UNION ALL

   -- Recursive step
   SELECT
      d.DepartmentId,
       d.Name,
      d.IsInactive,
      d.IsSpecial,
      d.ParentId,
      dh.HierarchyLevel + 1 AS HierarchyLevel
   FROM StoreDepartment d
      INNER JOIN DepartmentHierarchy dh ON
         d.ParentId = dh.DepartmentId
) SELECT * FROM DepartmentHierarchy
```

I am able to select data which looks like this:

```
DepartmentId, Name, IsInactive, IsSpecial, ParentId, HeirarchyLevel
1, Store, 0, 0, NULL, 1
2, Main Department 1, 0, 1, 2
3, Main Department 2, 0, 1, 2
4, Sub For Main 1, 0, 2, 3
```

Also, assume a table exists with DepartmentId and ItemId (ex: DepartmentItemRelationship).  Leaf nodes from the department heirarchy are paired with items here.

I want my recursive query to only return nodes (at any level) that have at least one leaf node below them with an match in the department/item relationship table. These nodes could be 6 or 7 levels down, so I'm not sure how I would amend my query to be sure to include those.

Thanks,
Kyle

Comment: Kyle, if you have a leaf node that meet the requirement in a level 6, do you want to show the the 5 departments above that node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a path column that keeps track of the hierarchy. Then you can only add the children nodes that have a match in the DepartmentItemRelationship table. And finally get only the nodes that at least have a child.

Try something like this:

```
    WITH DepartmentHierarchy (DepartmentID, Name, IsInactive, IsSpecial, ParentId, HierarchyLevel) AS
(
   -- Base case
   SELECT
      '/'+cast( DepartmentId as varchar(max)) as [path]
      DepartmentId,
      Name,
      IsInactive,
      IsSpecial,
      ParentId,
      1 as HierarchyLevel
   FROM StoreDepartment
   WHERE ParentId IS NULL

   UNION ALL

   -- Recursive step
   SELECT
      dh.[path] +'/'+ cast( d.DepartmentId as varchar(max)) as [path]
      d.DepartmentId,
      d.Name,
      d.IsInactive,
      d.IsSpecial,
      d.ParentId,
      dh.HierarchyLevel + 1 AS HierarchyLevel
   FROM StoreDepartment d
      INNER JOIN DepartmentHierarchy dh ON
         d.ParentId = dh.DepartmentId
   where exists ( select top 1 1 
                  from DepartmentItemRelationship di
                  where di.DepartmentId = d.DepartmentId )
) 
SELECT * 
FROM DepartmentHierarchy dh
where exists ( select top 1 1 
               from DepartmentHierarchy 
               where charindex('/'+dh.DepartmentID+'/',[path]) > 0)
```

Comment: This works brilliantly.  Just having the path of traversal through the tree will help me resolve which records I need to return.  (note: I removed the 'TOP' clause since it was not allowed in a recursive query).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want all nodes that are exactly one level above the leaf level?

You don't actually need a recursive query for this.  All you have to is first find the leaf nodes, then select all the parents.

```
WITH LeafNodeParents AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ParentId
    FROM StoreDepartment
    WHERE DepartmentId NOT IN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ParentId FROM StoreDepartment
    )
)
SELECT d.DepartmentId, d.Name, d.IsInactive, d.IsSpecial, d.ParentId
FROM LeafNodeParents p
INNER JOIN StoreDepartment d
    ON d.DepartmentId = p.ParentId
```

The only thing this won't tell you is the level.  I'm not sure how badly you need that.  If you don't, this should perform way better than the recursive version; if you do, it looks like Jose's query is OK for that (judging by a quick glance).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did accept the other answer because it allowed me to obtain data from all nodes.  I still appreciate (and upvoted) your answer.